# URL data to textbox need help - PHP

Tags: url, textbox

I very, very new to PHP so please forgive me if I don't get my question just right.

I have a program that connects to a Web server and passes a value. I was able to get the value to show up in the page, but I also need the same value to show up in a PayPal.

This code grabs the value from the URL and is working:

```
` <?php

// The value of the variable name is found
echo "<h3>Service Code: " . $_GET["sc"] . "</h3>";

?>`
```

Here's where I'm having the problem. I have no clue how to get the code into the textbox.

```
`  <?php 
$custom = $_POST['sc'];
?>`  

`<table>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value=". <?php echo $custom; ?>.
">Enter Service Code Here</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0"
maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>`
```

The complete form action:

```
`<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="AWSEDRFTGYHUJFDRRYGHGHF">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Enter Service Code Here">Enter Service  Code Here</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value=". <?php echo $sc; ?>.">
```

To this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="<?=$custom;?>">
```

1) The periods after the string declaration and before the end of it are most likely causing problems because it is not a php string being added to another php string.

2) The variable you set is `$custom`, not `$sc`.

3) *Optional*: `<?=` is just a shorter way of saying `<?php echo`.  Either one works here but this one is easier.

Comment: When you say that it is not working, that is vague.  Is it not sending the data, not receiving it, or simply showing a blank page?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="<?php echo $_POST['sc']; ?>" />
```

(remove the dots)

If that is what you're asking for?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried both answers, but neither worked. Am I missing something. If I look at the source code for my web page, I see my working code, but nothing else. Working:   ` <?php

// The value of the variable name is found
echo "<h3>Service Code: " . $_GET["sc"] . "</h3>";

?>`

Comment: So just to be sure, you want to grab a GET variable from the URL, and show that in a input field, type="text"?